# Shell Script failing on alpine linux while working in mac terminal

Tags: bash, shell, alpine-linux

The following line fails when run in a alpine docker container:

```
toDelete=( $(curl --silent $url/_cat/indices\?format=json | jq -r '.[].index | select(startswith('\".kibana\"'))') )
```

The following error message appears:

```
run.sh: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

When I run the command in the terminal on my mac, everything works properly. The brackets are added so that the result (variable toDelete) is interpreted as array and can be looped through with a for loop like so:

```
for index in "${toDelete[@]}"; do
    curl -X DELETE $url/$index
done
```

Any help in how to solve this problem is appreciated!

Comment: the interpreter is bash or sh ?

Comment: Good question, I start the script as Docker ENTRYPOINT with ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "run.sh"], thus it results in sh run.sh. Moreover it seems that the interpreter is ash (without the "B") which is why the brackets don't work.

Comment: What displays `ls -l /bin/sh`? A symbolic link towards what shell? Also, it seems like you want to set an array variable. True?

Comment: @user2074945 I believe it is working now. Please accept the answer so that the question can be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking down the answer.

The issue was with the interpreter.

worked after making the below change.

```
["/bin/ash", "run.sh"]
```

the passed one was

```
["/bin/sh", "run.sh"]
```